# CakePHP 3 send mail without using template, but with vars

Tags: email, cakephp-3.0

I'm sending email in CakePHP 3. The email content will be from db, not using template. The content has some variables that should be rendered before sending email. Here is my code

```
$email = new Email('default');
$email->emailFormat('html')
        ->helpers(['Html'])
        ->viewVars($vars)
        ->from($from)
        ->to($email)
        ->subject($subject);

$email->send($content);
```

I expected `$vars` would be rendered to `$content`, but it doesn't work. For example, I have `Dear <?=$guestName?>,` in the content, I just got `Dear,` in the mail received. HTML format is not working too. It did work when I use template. What am I wrong?

Comment: 'viewVars': If you are using rendered content, set the array with variables to be used in the view. See Email::viewVars(). https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html

Comment: @bikash.bilz I have read that doc thoroughly. I don't see a way that I want to implement as described in my question.

Comment: Pretty sure that the argument of `send()` should be a string that is the email content. Without a template, passing a view variable does nothing. I think you should make it like: `$content = 'Dear ' . $name . ',';` and don't pass view cars.